# SPI Chip select queries

Tags: spi

I have one query regarding SPI communication. I know in order to start communication, CS (Chip Select) signal needs to be asserted(high to Low) and in order to stop communication, CS needs to be deasserted(low to high). But lets say I want to do the SPI communication only one time at powerup, so after asserting the CS signal(to start communication), is it necessary to de assert the CS signal again, in order to read the values. I tried SPI communiaion,by asserting the CS at the start up, and inorder to stop the communication, unknowingly instead of deasserting CS, I again asserted the CS signal. But anyways, I didnt get the value. But however , when I corrected it, I was able to read the value. Can someone please explain this behavior?

Comment: Depends on what you're trying to talk to.

Comment: I didnt get you. are you not able to understand my query?

Comment: You haven't specified what you're trying to communicate with on your SPI bus. Different devices behave ... differently. Some may want you to assert CS, send something, release CS, re-assert CS, read something, release CS, while others might work with a single assert/release of CS. So tell us what you're talking to and someone might be able to help you further.

Comment: You say that instead of de-asserting CS, you instead asserted it again. CS can only be in two states. If it's already asserted and you try to assert it again, nothing happens! That's like setting a variable to 1 while it's already set to 1. Nothing happens.

Comment: Yes, But i should be able to atleast read the values sent by slave. Atleast I  should see the bit transmitted from slave before asserting it again. But I didnt see anything from the slave for every clock shift in the oscilloscope also.

Answer (score 2):

The chip-select pin on many devices generally serves some combination of the following five purposes:

1. To indicate that the device should react to incoming clock pulses rather than ignoring them.
2. To indicate that the device should drive MISO rather than floating it.
3. To indicate that the next clock pulse should be regarded as the start of a new byte.
4. To indicate that the next clock pulse should be regarded as the start of a new transaction or command.
5. To signal that the device should act upon the preceding transaction or command.

Different devices have different requirements with regard to /CS, but the normal pattern which should work with almost all devices is to release /CS if it isn't already, then assert it, send a command or transaction, and then release it.  Some devices may tolerate other ways of doing things, but the above pattern will work with almost all of them; in the absence of some reason not to use the pattern, I wouldn't worry about why other patterns may or may not work.  Simply use the indicated pattern and all will be good.

Comment: That's fine. But i want to do the SPI communication only one time at power up. So I dont need another clock pulse and hence no transaction next time. So is it necessary to release CS line once it is asserted(high to low). ?

Comment: @xyz101: That's the point -- unless you tell us what *specific* device you're working with, we can't say for sure.

Comment: Ok, I am working with a sensor device which act as slave. Its protocol is, Assert the CS signal, Transmit and receive the data simultaneously and then release the CS signal to stop the communication.

Comment: @xyz101: Some devices will perform some action when /CS is released; others won't.  If you don't care about anything the device does once you've got your data, or how much current it takes (many devices use more current when /CS is asserted than when it isn't), etc. then keeping /CS asserted won't undo any of the earlier effects you did care about.  Unless you're one instruction short of fitting your code in your device, however, I'd recommend releasing /CS as a matter of habit.